# GLSL Rounded Rectangle with Variable Border

Tags: geometry, glsl, shader, rectangles

I'm trying to write a GLSL shader that produces a rounded rectangle with a border, similar to the example below but where each border edge (top, bottom, left, right) can have a different thickness.

So, rather than a uniform borderThickness, we would have:
borderThicknessX0, borderThicknessX1, borderThicknessY0, borderThicknessY1

I've looked at numerous examples of creating a rounded rect in a shader using signed-distance fields (SDF), but have not figured out how to adapt the code to allow for variable border edge thickness.

It seems many approaches involve abs() of the fragment coordinate, therefore assuming uniformity.

Can anyone provide any guidance on how to achieve this?
Thanks!

[image: rounded rectangle with border]

example: [rounded rect with constant border](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ltS3zW)
example: [rounded rect with no border](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ldfSDj)

Comment: Have you tried to make the rectangle centered on **0,0** and make each section (**x,y** then **-x,y** then **-x,-y**...) different ? you can achive this easly

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you elaborate on "make each section (x,y then -x,y then -x,-y...)", not sure I understand what you're describing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In compare to the shadertoy shader ([rounded rect with constant border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59197671/glsl-rounded-rectangle-with-variable-border)) you've to calculate the `u_fHalfBorderThickness` dependent on the fragment.

Define a thickness for the left, right, bottom and top:

```c
float u_ThicknessTop    = 20.0;
float u_ThicknessBottom = 30.0;
float u_ThicknessLeft   = 25.0;
float u_ThicknessRight  = 35.0;
```

Calculate the thickness of the edges dependent on the section:

```c
vec2 uv = fragCoord / iResolution;
vec2 edgeThickness = vec2(
    uv.x > 0.5 ? u_ThicknessRight : u_ThicknessLeft,
    uv.y > 0.5 ? u_ThicknessTop : u_ThicknessBottom );
```

Calculate the `fHalfBorderThickness`dependent on the fragment and the distance (`fHalfBorderDist`) of the fragment to the center of the border:

```c
float fHalfBorderDist      = 0.0;
float fHalfBorderThickness = 0.0;
if (fragCoord.x > max(u_fRadiusPx, u_ThicknessLeft) && 
    fragCoord.x < u_resolution.x - max(u_fRadiusPx, u_ThicknessRight))
{
    fHalfBorderDist      = v2CenteredPos.y - v2HalfShapeSizePx.y;
    fHalfBorderThickness = v2edgeThickness.y / 2.0; 
}
else if (fragCoord.y > max(u_fRadiusPx, u_ThicknessBottom) && 
            fragCoord.y < u_resolution.y - max(u_fRadiusPx, u_ThicknessTop))
{
    fHalfBorderDist      = v2CenteredPos.x - v2HalfShapeSizePx.x;
    fHalfBorderThickness = v2edgeThickness.x / 2.0;
}
else
{
    vec2 edgeVec = max(vec2(0.0), u_fRadiusPx - vec2(
        uv.x > 0.5 ? iResolution.x-fragCoord.x : fragCoord.x,
        uv.y > 0.5 ? iResolution.y-fragCoord.y : fragCoord.y));

    vec2 ellipse_ab    = u_fRadiusPx-v2edgeThickness;
    vec2 ellipse_isect = (v2edgeThickness.x > u_fRadiusPx || v2edgeThickness.y > u_fRadiusPx) ? vec2(0.0) :
                            edgeVec.xy * ellipse_ab.x*ellipse_ab.y / length(ellipse_ab*edgeVec.yx); 

    fHalfBorderThickness = (u_fRadiusPx - length(ellipse_isect)) / 2.0;
    fHalfBorderDist      = length(edgeVec) - (u_fRadiusPx - fHalfBorderThickness);
}
```

Note, the inner rounding of the border is an ellipse. To verify if a point is on the border, you've to intersect the line from the center point of the rounding, to the current fragment with the ellipse. See [Ellipse-Line Intersection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse-LineIntersection.html)

```c
vec2 ellipse_ab    = u_fRadiusPx-v2edgeThickness;
vec2 ellipse_isect = edgeVec.xy * ellipse_ab.x*ellipse_ab.y / length(ellipse_ab*edgeVec.yx);
```

See the example:

```js
(function loadscene() {    

var canvas, gl, vp_size, prog, bufObj = {};

function initScene() {

    canvas = document.getElementById( "ogl-canvas");
    gl = canvas.getContext( "experimental-webgl" );
    if ( !gl )
      return;

    progDraw = gl.createProgram();
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        let source = document.getElementById(i==0 ? "draw-shader-vs" : "draw-shader-fs").text;
        let shaderObj = gl.createShader(i==0 ? gl.VERTEX_SHADER : gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        gl.shaderSource(shaderObj, source);
        gl.compileShader(shaderObj);
        let status = gl.getShaderParameter(shaderObj, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
        if (!status) alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shaderObj));
        gl.attachShader(progDraw, shaderObj);
        gl.linkProgram(progDraw);
    }
    status = gl.getProgramParameter(progDraw, gl.LINK_STATUS);
    if ( !status ) alert(gl.getProgramInfoLog(progDraw));
    progDraw.inPos = gl.getAttribLocation(progDraw, "inPos");
    progDraw.u_resolution = gl.getUniformLocation(progDraw, "u_resolution");
    progDraw.u_ThicknessTop = gl.getUniformLocation(progDraw, "u_ThicknessTop");
    progDraw.u_ThicknessBottom = gl.getUniformLocation(progDraw, "u_ThicknessBottom");
    progDraw.u_ThicknessLeft = gl.getUniformLocation(progDraw, "u_ThicknessLeft");
    progDraw.u_ThicknessRight = gl.getUniformLocation(progDraw, "u_ThicknessRight");
    gl.useProgram(progDraw);

    var pos = [ -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1 ];
    var inx = [ 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 ];
    bufObj.pos = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.pos );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array( pos ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    bufObj.inx = gl.createBuffer();
    bufObj.inx.len = inx.length;
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.inx );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array( inx ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( progDraw.inPos );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( progDraw.inPos, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 ); 
    
    gl.enable( gl.DEPTH_TEST );
    gl.clearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

    window.onresize = resize;
    resize();
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function resize() {
    //vp_size = [gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight];
    vp_size = [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight];
    //vp_size = [256, 256]
    canvas.width = vp_size[0];
    canvas.height = vp_size[1];
}

function render(deltaMS) {

    var top = document.getElementById("top").value;
    var bottom = document.getElementById("bottom").value;
    var left = document.getElementById("left").value;
    var right = document.getElementById("right").value;

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
   
    gl.uniform2f(progDraw.u_resolution, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    gl.uniform1f(progDraw.u_ThicknessTop, top);
    gl.uniform1f(progDraw.u_ThicknessBottom, bottom);
    gl.uniform1f(progDraw.u_ThicknessLeft, left);
    gl.uniform1f(progDraw.u_ThicknessRight, right);
    gl.drawElements( gl.TRIANGLES, bufObj.inx.len, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0 );
    
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}  

initScene();

})();
```

```css
#gui { position : absolute; top : 0; left : 0; font-size : large; }
```

```html
<script id="draw-shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
precision mediump float;

attribute vec2 inPos;

void main()
{
    //ndcPos = inPos;
    gl_Position = vec4( inPos.xy, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
</script>

<script id="draw-shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

//varying vec2 ndcPos;  // normaliced device coordinates in range [-1.0, 1.0]
uniform float u_time;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;

uniform float u_ThicknessTop;
uniform float u_ThicknessBottom;
uniform float u_ThicknessLeft;
uniform float u_ThicknessRight;

const vec4 u_v4BorderColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
const vec4 u_v4FillColor   = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
const float u_fRadiusPx    = 50.0;

void main()
{
    vec2 iResolution = u_resolution;
    vec2 fragCoord   = gl_FragCoord.xy;
   
    vec2 uv = fragCoord / iResolution;
    vec2 v2edgeThickness = vec2(
        uv.x > 0.5 ? u_ThicknessRight : u_ThicknessLeft,
        uv.y > 0.5 ? u_ThicknessTop : u_ThicknessBottom );
    
    vec2 v2CenteredPos     = abs(fragCoord - iResolution.xy / 2.0);
    vec2 v2HalfShapeSizePx = iResolution/2.0 - v2edgeThickness/2.0;    

    float fHalfBorderDist      = 0.0;
    float fHalfBorderThickness = 0.0;
    if (fragCoord.x > max(u_fRadiusPx, u_ThicknessLeft) && 
        fragCoord.x < u_resolution.x - max(u_fRadiusPx, u_ThicknessRight))
    {
        fHalfBorderDist      = v2CenteredPos.y - v2HalfShapeSizePx.y;
        fHalfBorderThickness = v2edgeThickness.y / 2.0; 
    }
    else if (fragCoord.y > max(u_fRadiusPx, u_ThicknessBottom) && 
             fragCoord.y < u_resolution.y - max(u_fRadiusPx, u_ThicknessTop))
    {
        fHalfBorderDist      = v2CenteredPos.x - v2HalfShapeSizePx.x;
        fHalfBorderThickness = v2edgeThickness.x / 2.0;
    }
    else
    {
        vec2 edgeVec = max(vec2(0.0), u_fRadiusPx - vec2(
            uv.x > 0.5 ? iResolution.x-fragCoord.x : fragCoord.x,
            uv.y > 0.5 ? iResolution.y-fragCoord.y : fragCoord.y));
        
        vec2 ellipse_ab    = u_fRadiusPx-v2edgeThickness;
        vec2 ellipse_isect = (v2edgeThickness.x > u_fRadiusPx || v2edgeThickness.y > u_fRadiusPx) ? vec2(0.0) :
                                edgeVec.xy * ellipse_ab.x*ellipse_ab.y / length(ellipse_ab*edgeVec.yx); 
            
        fHalfBorderThickness = (u_fRadiusPx - length(ellipse_isect)) / 2.0;
        fHalfBorderDist      = length(edgeVec) - (u_fRadiusPx - fHalfBorderThickness);
    }

    vec4 v4FromColor = u_v4BorderColor; 
    vec4 v4ToColor   = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    if (fHalfBorderDist < 0.0)
        v4ToColor = u_v4FillColor;
    
    gl_FragColor = mix(v4FromColor, v4ToColor, abs(fHalfBorderDist) - fHalfBorderThickness);
}
</script>

<div><form id="gui" name="inputs">
  <table>
  <tr> <td> top </td> 
      <td> <input type="range" id="top" min="1" max="100" value="20"/>
  </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td> bottom </td> 
      <td> <input type="range" id="bottom" min="1" max="100" value="30"/>
  </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td> left </td> 
      <td> <input type="range" id="left" min="1" max="100" value="25" />
  </td></tr>
  <tr> <td> right </td> 
      <td> <input type="range" id="right" min="1" max="100" value="35"/>
  </td> </tr>
  </table>
</form></div>

<canvas id="ogl-canvas" style="border: none"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your thorough answer. There seems to be a bug in the shader code. 
See https://pasteboard.co/IK0lXhv.png 
Config:
u_resolution = vec2(100.0,100.0);
u_fRadiusPx = 20.0;
u_ThicknessTop = 12.0;
u_ThicknessBottom = 18.0;
u_ThicknessLeft =  6.0;
u_ThicknessRight = 20.0;

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks so much, looking forward to it!

Comment: Thanks @Rabbid76, I think there's still an issue when u_fRadiusPx is less than any of the component edge thicknesses.

Comment: Hmm. If u_fRadiusPx == 0 and borders are > 0, you'd have a rectangle inside a rectangle. https://pasteboard.co/IK2Lysl.png